# mvc model with a foreign key, connection lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 models, Artist and Album.
Artist have a collection of albums.
Album have a foreigm key to Artist (int artistId).

Now in my site you get to select the album for edition from its artist,
and when I send the album back to the controller, its artistId always 0 (default value of int) and I failed to save the album, because there is no such artist with 0 id. How I'm losing the id of the artist?

the artist

```
public class Artist
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public string NickName { get; set; }

        public string Website { get; set; }

        public string Facebook { get; set; }

        public string Twitter { get; set; }

        public string Wikipedia { get; set; }

        public string Background { get; set; }

        public long StartYearActivity { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }

        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
```

the album

```
 public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ArtistId { get; set; }

        public string Genre { get; set; }

        public string Wikipedia { get; set; }

        public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int NumOfSongs { get { return this.Songs != null ? this.Songs.Count : 0; } }

        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

the save method for album when the artist id is null:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditAlbum([Bind(Include = "Id,Genre,Wikipedia,Name,Year")] Album album)
    {
        db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(album);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How would we know? Got any code?

Comment: Does adding "ArtistId" to your EditAlbum action's bind help? e.g. try [Bind(Include = "Id,ArtistId,Genre,Wikipedia,Name,Year")]

Comment: Can you confirm if the ArtistId is present in your Edit View?